# Indeterminate (circular) ProgressBar freezes in ViewPager (with FragmentStatePagerAdapter)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, progress-bar

**Background:** I have a simple `Activity` with a `ViewPager` which uses a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` adapter. Adapter provides 5 Fragments. On every page of the `ViewPager` I have a simple `Fragment` which holds only an indeterminate (circular) `ProgressBar`. I also have a custom tab view on top to be able to switch tabs/fragments easily.

**The problem** is that if I start the activity and I navigate to a Tab 3, 4 or 5 (so to a Tab which is not cached) then the `ProgressBar` is freezed, it is not animating.

**Notices:** As far as I experienced, if `getOffscreenPageLimit` covers all of the possible Tabs (so in my case if `getOffscreenPageLimit() == 4`) are loaded, then the issue never happens. Problem only occurres when I switch to a tab which needs to be rendered when I move to it: so if I use the default `OffscreenPageLimit` then the first 2 Tabs are good, but not the third one.

`Activity:`

```
public class SpinnerTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);

        final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // setting up custom tabview
        SlidingTabLayout tabs = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return ContextCompat.getColor(SpinnerTest.this, R.color.colorAccent);
            }

            @Override
            public int getDividerColor(int position) {
                return ContextCompat.getColor(SpinnerTest.this, android.R.color.transparent);
            }
        });
        tabs.setViewPager(mPager);

    }

    private static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new SpinnerFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Tab" + (position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

    }

}
```

`activity_spinner.xml:`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`Fragment:`

```
public class SpinnerFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spinner, container, false);
    }

}
```

`fragment_spinner.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does this keep happening even if you use a 'FragmentPagerAdapter'?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same behavior. Playing around with `setOffscreenPageLimit(x)` ends up with the same result as with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.